# Why am I get CGI default page whenever I try to access my AWS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, server, cgi

I'm new to AWS EC2 hosting, I have created an instance that has a 'cPanel-WHM for Linux' security group name; by using amazon Route 53 I have set a hosted zone, which I use to link with my domain from NameCheap. My domain from Namecheap is pointing to this hosted zone which has an A record pointing to the IP address of my instance. I have logged in to Cpanel direct by using an IP address with port:2087 and adding an index.php file that contains some simple code to display the welcome note. but whenever I go to this domain I get the default CGI page
"cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi"

I have checked my DNS propagation and I have seen the DNS is propagated. I have tried several times, I thought there was a place I mess with instance settings but ended up with the same problem. Is anyone have any idea what is going on? Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: What software have you installed on the instance? What happens if you go to the IP address (eg `http://1.2.3.4`)? The issue would be related to the configuration of your software on the instance, not the Domain Name.

Comment: If I go to the IP address as the way you mentioned, it responds as expected (displaying index file content). The only thing is installed in the instance I think is Cpanel as it comes with the whm Linux image

Comment: Presumably you installed something that acts as a web server. It would need to be configured to handle your domain name as a 'virtual host'. You might receive a better answer at: https://serverfault.com/

Comment: Okay let me try there